# How many ways can 5 prizes be distributed among 4 students, where each is eligible for all the 5 prizes ? (i.e. repetition allowed)

Tags: combinatorics

The answer says $1024$, which I guess is coming from $4^5$. So its like "$4$ students fit into each prize" $+$ repeats allowed + $5$ prizes $= 4^5 = 1024$.

Why not "$5$ prizes for each student" $+$ repeats allowed $+ 4$ students , thus $5^4 = 625$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each prize comes with a list of four students.  When the judge awards the first prize, she chooses one of the four to win the prize.  When she awards the second prize, there are again four choices.  Continue, to get $$4\times 4\times 4\times 4\times 4=4^5$$
possible outcomes for awarding the prizes.

$5^4$ would be the answer if there were five grades, not five prizes, and each student earned exactly one of the five grades.  Repetition is allowed, i.e. two students can get the same grade.

Comment: very helpful explanation.

Comment: It feels like "decide your domain and co-domain" kinda stuff. When repeats are allowed, for each entry in the domain, you get all the entries in the co-domain. Does this make any sense ?

Comment: Just an idea. This question does not say anything about:- “it is possible that some of the prizes could have not been given out for the reason of not meeting their qaulifing requirements.”

Answer (score 0):

You say 5 prizes for each student but there are only 5 prizes so the rest 3 boys will get no prize hence we.will solve it by4^5